# TideSDK, windows app run from external drive, no install

Tags: tidesdk

I have successfully translated a web app into a desktop app using TideSDK. I'm attempting to make this app run without being installed, so it may run from an external drive. On MAC this works just fine, I'm able able to "Package with Runtime", copy the app to an external drive, and the app works as expected.

When I package the app on Windows, it runs properly when tested inside the /packages folder, but when I copy it to an external drive, it does not appear to connect with the database or perform TideSDK operations ( Ti.UI.createMenu() ) that should be happening when I open my app.

Do Windows apps packaged with TideSDK have to be installed on the C:/ drive? Does the API expect the app to be on the C:/ drive in order to function? Is it possible to do what I am attempting to do on Windows via TideSDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmmm. When u do a package with runtime in tideSDK for MAC

It actually generates two files

.app # .app file will have all its dependencies inside the same file(Actually .app file is also a folder, u can check this in editor like sublime)

.dmg file( Consider it like the compressed file .app)

However in windows, It generates one installer file and folder(named by app name)

This folder has its all the dependencies for the app to run.

So if you want to run the app you have to copy the complete folder

To answer your question,

At this point I don't think tideSDK has a feature to create a single .exe file that can run from external drive

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Abibdullah, that is exactly what I was doing wrong. I needed to copy the entire windows folder created during packaging, and copy that to the external drive. What it seems I was doing incorrectly was I copied only the Contents of that package folder for my app to the root of the external drive. Furthermore what I also did was First package with Runtime in TideSDK Developer, the run the Windows Installation Package created (.msi), Then I had copied the folder from C:\Program Files (XP) to my external drive and it worked perfectly, no installation required.